# How to replace character in a JSON

Tags: apex, json, jsongenerator

I have a requirement where i need to create the below JSON -

```
{ id: 1, "tags": ["Management"], name: "Amber McKenzie", title: "CEO", img: "https://cdn.balkan.app/shared/1.jpg" }
```

I am able to create the JSON , but got stuck in `"tags": ["Management"]`

I am trying the below code, but it creates like tags: `"[\"External\"]"`

```
JSONGenerator jsonGen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
string g = '["External"]';
jsonGen.writeStartArray(); 
jsonGen.writeStartObject();
jsonGen.writeStringField('tags',g); 
jsonGen.writeEndObject();
jsonGen.writeEndArray();
system.debug(jsonGen.getAsString().replace('\'',''));
```

How can i make it like this `"tags": ["Management"]`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `JSON.serialize` for it.

```
public class SomeClass {
    public void doSomethingWithRequest(String params) {
        // if you want to parse
        Wrapper wrapper = (Wrapper) JSON.deserialize(params, Wrapper.class);
        
        // if you want to generate;
        Wrapper wrapper2 = new Wrapper();
        // fill fields then
        System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(wrapper2));
        
        // or you can do like this
        Map<String, Object> someObj = new Map<String, Object> {
                'name' => 'wfwef',
                'title' => 'sdf',
                'tags' => new List<String> {
                        '1','2','3'
                }
        };

        System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(someObj));
    }
    
    public class Wrapper{
        public String name{get;set;}
        public String title{get;set;}
        public list<String> tags{get;set;}
        public String img{get;set;}
        public Integer id{get;set;}
    }
}
```

if you want to use JSONGenerator for it you can use `writeObjectField`  like this

```
JSONGenerator jsonGen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
string g = '["External"]';
jsonGen.writeStartArray(); 
jsonGen.writeStartObject();
jsonGen.writeObjectField('tags', new List<String> {'External'}); 
jsonGen.writeEndObject();
jsonGen.writeEndArray();
system.debug(jsonGen.getAsString().replace('\'',''));
```

Comment: typo??`JSON.stringify` is a javascript method. Your code samples are correct

Comment: you're correct I had a typo, I meant JSON.serialize) Sorry, for some reason didn't check the first line before submitting)

Comment: fixed it, thanks. if my examples work for you, please accept the answer